# Return IQueryable<string>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I'm using pageList (the one made by troy goode), on his example he has

```
// in this case we return IEnumerable<string>, but in most
// - DB situations you'll want to return IQueryable<string>
private IEnumerable<string> GetStuffFromDatabase()
{
    var sampleData = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Names.txt")).ReadToEnd();
    return sampleData.Split('\n');
}
```

Since i'm using a database i changed to `IQueryable`, but, i don't know what to write inside to return the data from the database, i tried changing the path to ~/App_Data/DatabaseName.sdf but i get that `sampleData.Split('\n');`

`cannot implicitly convert type string to system.linq.iqueryable<string>`

How i can change that?

Answer (score 0):

```
return sampleData.Split('\n').AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Of this part of the code `public ActionResult Index(int ? page)
        {
            var listPaged = GetPagedNames(page);
            if (listPaged == null)
                {
                return HttpNotFound();
                }

            ViewBag.Names = listPaged;
            return View(db.Productos.ToList());
        }`

Comment: Give me "DataException was unhandled by user code, an exception ocurred while initializing the database. See the inner exception for details" this error on the line of this line `return View(db.Productos.ToList());`

Comment: You should probably change the code in the question to reflect the code you are actually working with to enable us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of your method is IEnumerable and requires to return as Enumeration

so please do this way

```
return sampleData.Split('\n').AsEnumerable();
```